# automatize a mathematic procedure: I need industrial amouts of results, and I get one

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've the following simple code in mathematica that is what I want to a **single** output. But I want to get hundreds or thousands of it. How can I do?

```
Clear["Global`*"]


k = 2; Put["phiout"]; Put["omegadiffout"];

Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]];

For[i = 1, i < 31,
 rnd[i] = Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]; i++]

Table[rnd[i], {i, 1, 30}]

For[i = 1, i < 30,
 rnddf[i] = rnd[i + 1] - rnd[i]; i++
 ]

diffomega = Table [rnddf[i], {i, 1, 29}];


Table[
  Table [rnddf[i], {i, 1, 29}], {j, 1, 100}];

PutAppend[Table[
  diffomega, {j, 1, 100}] , "diffomega"]


eqs0 = Table  [
   k*phi[i + 1] + k*phi[i - 1] - 2*k*phi[i] - rnddf[i] == 0, {i, 1, 
    28}];

eqs1 = eqs0 /. {phi[0] -> phi[30], phi[31] -> phi[1]};

Sum[phi[i], {i, 1, 29}];

eqs2 = Append[eqs1, - phi[1] - phi[27] - 3 phi[29] == 0];

eqs3 = eqs2 /. {phi[30] -> -Sum[phi[i], {i, 1, 29}]};

vars = Table  [phi[i], {i, 1, 29}];

eqs = NSolve[eqs3, vars];

PutAppend[diffomega, eqs , "phiout"]
```

This put on file "phiout" and "omegadiffout" only the last value. I need hundreds of them. For each random generations I need an output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the third line do? Also, could you *indent* the bodies of the loops? It is hard to read.

Comment: At the moment you don't seem to be writing anything at all to "omegadiffout", though you are writing 100 copies of `diffomega` to "diffomega".  It looks like you should be able to repeat your code by just wrapping the relevant part in a `For[...]` loop - does that not work?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you need to do, @Paulo, is tidy up your *Mathematica* so that you, and we, can see the wood for the trees.  For example, your 8th statement:

```
Table[
  Table [rnddf[i], {i, 1, 29}], {j, 1, 100}];
```

makes a large table, but the table isn't assigned to a variable or used in any other way.  There seem to be other statements whose results aren't used either.

Next you should abandon your `For` loops and use the *Mathematica* idioms -- they are clearer for we who use *Mathematica* regularly to understand, easier for you to write, and probably more efficient too.  Your statements

```
For[i = 1, i < 31,
 rnd[i] = Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]; i++]

Table[rnd[i], {i, 1, 30}]

For[i = 1, i < 30,
 rnddf[i] = rnd[i + 1] - rnd[i]; i++
 ]

diffomega = Table [rnddf[i], {i, 1, 29}];
```

can, if I understand correctly, be replaced by:

```
diffomega = Differences[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,0.1],{30}]];
```

Always remember that if you are writing loops in Mathematica you are probably making a mistake.  The next change you should make is to stop using `Put` and `PutAppend` until you can build, in memory, at least a small example of the entire output that you want to write.  Then write that to a file in one go with `Save` or `Export` or one of the other high-level I/O functions.

When you have done that, edit your code and explain what you are trying to do and I, and other SOers, will try to help further.  Unfortunately, right now, your code is so un-*Mathematica*-al that I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: You don't even need the `Table` when you want to draw a whole lot of reals from a random distribution; just use the second argument of `RandomReal`.